# python ctypes.CDLL does not load library although location is know

Tags: python, ctypes, importerror, shapely

To run one of my script I have to use the shapely python package, but it crashes because it cannot load the libgeos library. It gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_nl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from download_sentinel import sentinel_available, sentinel_download,     download_orbits
  File "/nfs/home2/gmulder/radar_database/download_sentinel.py", line 14, in <module>
    from fastkml import kml
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/fastkml/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .kml import KML, Document, Folder, Placemark
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/fastkml/kml.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .geometry import Geometry
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/fastkml/geometry.py", line 23, in <module>
    from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/shapely/coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/shapely/geos.py", line 73, in <module>
    _lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])
  File "/home/gmulder/python_packages/shapely/geos.py", line 68, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'].
```

However, the strange thing is that, when I run python interactively, the import goes fine and I do not get any errors. To check whether it is a problem with setting the right paths, I also checked the source. The original code is the following, where the libname gives the library name.

```
def load_dll(libname, fallbacks=None, mode=DEFAULT_MODE):
    lib = find_library(libname)
    dll = None
    print(sys.version)
    dirname = '/hpc/sw/geos-3.5.0/lib'
    os.environ['PATH'] = dirname + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirname, 'libgeos_c.so.1')):
        print('library does exist!')
    os.chdir(dirname)
    if lib is not None:
    try:
        LOG.debug("Trying `CDLL(%s)`", lib)
        dll = CDLL(lib)
    except OSError:
        LOG.warn("Failed `CDLL(%s)`", lib)
        pass

    if not dll and fallbacks is not None:
        for name in fallbacks:
            try:
                LOG.debug("Trying `CDLL(%s)`", name)
                dll = CDLL(name)
            except OSError:
                # move on to the next fallback
                LOG.warn("Failed `CDLL(%s)`", name)
                pass

    print(dll)
    if dll:
        LOG.debug("Library path: %r", lib or name)
        LOG.debug("DLL: %r", dll)
        return dll
    else:
        # No shared library was loaded. Raise OSError.
        raise OSError(
            "Could not find lib {0} or load any of its variants    {1}.".format(
                libname, fallbacks or []))
```

To check whether the needed lib file location can be found by the code I added an extra check at line 7, which confirms the library is there. But then, when I try to load it, nothing is loaded, even if I feed the full path to the CDLL function directly. 
I also tried to load the library by running python and opening the library interactively (not from a python script), which worked fine. Therefore, I checked the python versions, because I thought that could maybe cause this problem. But the python versions for my script and the interactive session are the same. Can someone help me with this? Likely I missed something, but I have no idea what is causing this problem.